# I want to split multiple columns in fixed rows. using power query or any other method in EXCEL

Tags: excel, pivot, powerquery

I have Excel sheet with table as per image.
I want to convert my table as shown in target.
Can anyone help me in same regards?

I think powerquery is the solution but
I am new to power query

[image]

I need output as per target sheet.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to group by itemcode and sum the values of each month?

Comment: Yes, I want group by item code.  Please see my ** Source ** image which iIhave data in Excel-Table. and i need final output as per *Target* Image. Actually I am new to stackoverflow... by mistake source image uploaded two time.

Comment: Please note : In source column AJan18, AFeb18 : A is Salesmen Name. We have fixed 3 salesmen (A, B,C). means i need output 3 rows ( A, B, C)  for each item and 5 columns ( Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May18 ) for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reverses the process from the wide image to the shorter one
[1] choose first column and unpivot all other columns [2] Choose column of column headers and split. Here I assumed I can split by the rightmost 5 characters to pull out MMMYY [3] Pivot on the new column showing just the MMMYY using the value column

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Item Code"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Split Column by Position" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByPositions({0, 5}, true), {"Attribute.1", "Attribute.2"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Split Column by Position", List.Distinct(#"Split Column by Position"[Attribute.2]), "Attribute.2", "Value", List.Sum)
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to go from the shorter image to the wider one (which was not apparently what you wanted, but leaving answer here anyway)

[1] Click on first two columns then right click and choose unpivot other columns  [2] Add custom column to merge Salesmen and Month columns using formula =[SalesMen]&Text.From([Attribute])  [3]  Click first two column then right click and choose GroupBy  Add a new column that uses the sum operation on the Value column   [4] Click column from step #2 and choose Transform ... Pivot Column and choose Total for values column

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"ItemCode", "SalesMen"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "SalesMenMonth", each [SalesMen]&Text.From([Attribute])),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"ItemCode", "SalesMenMonth"}, {{"Total", each List.Sum([Value]), type number}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Grouped Rows", List.Distinct(#"Grouped Rows"[SalesMenMonth]), "SalesMenMonth", "Total", List.Sum)
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution.  Still my question is not solved. Actually there is mistake in image upload.  What you have assumed as source.  It is actually my final output requirement.  Please note : I have available data which has 16 columns. I need final out put which has 7 columns.  Your solution is other way round.